# multi-page crawler gives wrong results

Tags: python, scrapy

Thanks in advance for your usefull help!

We need to crawl and save on our MySQL Database all the product pages from the website https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/

This website does not have a sitemap so we chose as the data source the summary webpage https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/Immobili/Riepilogo

From here you can see we have the first page as region, then province, then district and finally the product page we need to crawl and save.

We are developing this by using Scrapy and Python 3.8.5

During the execution flow from regions-page to products-page (entries) I pass data through the argument meta.

When I tested and printed to a CSV file in the format 'region','province','district' I get columns with wrong values.

The problem is when I run from terminal `scrapy crawl products -o f.csv` :

The output-file contains a table of 'region','province','district' but the row content is not correctly displayed as expected.

I don't understand what the bug can be into this code,

I appreciate very much your response and support for creating a better web!

Thank you!

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.http.request import Request

protocol = 'http://'
domain   = 'www.astegiudiziarie.it'
path     = '/Immobili/Riepilogo'

target_url = protocol + domain + path

dev_entry_counter = 0
dev_entry_limit   = 100

def file_debug (message) :
    f = open('debug.txt', 'a')
    f.write(message + "\n\n")
    f.close()

class ProductsSpider (scrapy.Spider) :
    name = 'products'
    allowed_domains = [domain]
    start_urls = [target_url]

    def parse (self, response) :# Parsing of 'regione' (Layer 1)
        regioni = response.xpath('//table[@id="panoramica"]/tbody/tr')
        
        for regione in regioni :# Iterating rows
            regione_name = regione.xpath('//th[@scope="rowgroup"]//text()').extract_first()
            
            hrefs_l1 = regione.xpath('//td/a/@href').extract()
            
            for href_l1 in hrefs_l1 :# Iterating columns
                abs_href_l1 = target_url + href_l1
                
                yield Request(url = abs_href_l1, callback = self.parse_provincia, meta = {'regione': regione_name})

    def parse_provincia (self, response) :# Parsing of 'provincia' (Layer 2)
        province = response.xpath('//table[@id="panoramica"]/tbody/tr')

        for provincia in province :
            provincia_name = provincia.xpath('//th[@scope="rowgroup"]//text()').extract_first()

            hrefs_l2 = provincia.xpath('//td/a/@href').extract()

            for href_l2 in hrefs_l2 :
                abs_href_l2 = target_url + href_l2

                yield Request(url = abs_href_l2, callback = self.parse_comune, meta = {'regione': response.meta['regione'],
                                                                                       'provincia' : provincia_name})

    def parse_comune (self, response) :# Parsing of 'comune' (Layer 3)
        comuni = response.xpath('//table[@id="panoramica"]/tbody/tr')

        for comune in comuni :
            comune_name = comune.xpath('//th[@scope="rowgroup"]//text()').extract_first()

            hrefs_l3 = comune.xpath('//td/a/@href').extract()

            for href_l3 in hrefs_l3 :
                abs_href_l3 = protocol + domain + href_l3

                yield Request(url = abs_href_l3, callback = self.parse_entries, meta = {'regione'   : response.meta['regione'],
                                                                                        'provincia' : response.meta['provincia'],
                                                                                        'comune'    : comune_name})

    def parse_entries (self, response) :# Parsing of 'entries' (list of the products)
        entries = response.xpath('//*[@class="listing-item"]')

        properties = {}

        properties['regione']   = response.meta['regione']
        properties['provincia'] = response.meta['provincia']
        properties['comune']    = response.meta['comune']

        yield properties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are looping through `Selector`s and calling the `xpath` method you should make your queries relative to the current selector using e.g. `./`.

So in your `parse` method you should use

```py
regione_name = regione.xpath('./th[@scope="rowgroup"]//text()').get()
```

other wise you'll just get the first `th` in the entire document.

Another tip for your use case, is to use `response.follow` instead of constructing the `Requests` as you are. For example your `parse` method (which is pretty much the same as your other methods) can become

```
def parse(self, response):
    for regione in response.xpath('//table[@id="panoramica"]/tbody/tr'):
        regione_name = regione.xpath('./th[@scope="rowgroup"]//text()').get()
        if not regione_name:
            continue

        for link in regione.xpath("./td/a"):
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_provincia, meta=...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!! Now it works correctly. You made me save a lot of debug time ...

Comment: @CapitanPNG Great, please mark the answer as accepted so others know your question has been addressed